# Trying to make bash script for ping

Tags: bash, shell-script

The below script is not working. Any help would be appreciated

```bsh
for host in `cat db_hosts_imsi.txt` ; do "ping6 $host"; done
```

```
-bash: ping6 2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:1d: command not found
-bash: ping6 2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:45: command not found
-bash: ping6 2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:54: command not found
```

Comment: Check if ping6 is installed on the VM/host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
while IFS= read -r host; do
    ping6 "$host"
done < db_hosts_imsi.txt
```

The main issue is quoting both the command and the argument together.

And to read a file line by line, always use `while` loop, not `for` loop.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Moreover, the

```
`command`
```

syntax is deprecated in 2020 in favor of the form

```
$(command)
```

The latest syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but am still getting issue

:~$ ./ping6.sh
unknown host
unknown host
unknown host

:~$ cat ping6.sh
while IFS= read -r host; do
    ping6 "$host"
done < db_hosts_imsi.txt

Comment: If you have 'unknown host', then the script works, but there's an issue reaching hosts via ICMPv6.

Comment: What is the output of `ip -br -6 a` and `which ping6` and `ping ipv6.google.com` ? (Assuming you are running Linux)

Comment: ip -br -6 a
lo               UNKNOWN        ::1/128
ens160           UP             fe80::250:56ff:fe89:4694/64
ens192           UP             fe80::250:56ff:fe89:a7f9/64
ens224           UP             2606:ae00:3001:8311:172:16:244:28/120 fe80::250:56ff:fe89:fa04/64
docker0          UP             fd00:dead:beef::1/48 fe80::42:22ff:feaa:9f72/64 fe80::1/64
vethb564aeb@if6  UP             fe80::6c54:3ff:fec8:51b7/64
veth7c685bd@if8  UP             fe80::184c:e2ff:fe76:8de5/64
vethd094955@if10 UP             fe80::48d2:45ff:fe8e:7aea/64

Comment: which ipv6
:~$ which ping6
/bin/ping6

~$ ping ipv6.google.com
ping: unknown host ipv6.google.com

Comment: Seems an issue with your DNS settings. As root: `cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak; echo 'nameserver 9.9.9.9' >  /etc/resolv.conf` then retry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109179/discussion-between-muhammad-ilyas-and-gilles-quenot).